# Password_verify not work properly

Tags: php, oop, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I try to make a login system in php using OOP. Works fine with this code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' &&
    !empty($_POST['email']) &&
    !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $loggedUser = Users::loadUserByEmail($conn, $email);

    if ($loggedUser != null) {
        $loggedUserId = $loggedUser->getId();
        $_SESSION['loggedUserId'] = $loggedUserId;
        header('Location: index.php');
    } else {
        $info = "Invalid login or password. Try again";
    }
} else {
    $info = "Invalid login or password. Try again";
}
```

But in this situation password isnt checked so I try to add password_verify function.

```
if ($loggedUser != null) {
    $hash = $loggedUser->getHashedPassword();
    if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
        $loggedUserId = $loggedUser->getId();
```

Next step manually check $hash and var_dump show correctly the same as in my DB but function returns false. What is incorrect?

Comment: Did you use password_hash to hash to password in the first place?

Comment: did you check the lengths of both variables?

Comment: You should add an `exit;` after your `header('Location: index.php');` to make sure your script stops executing.

Comment: There's not enough debugging and code details in your question to tell where you're going wrong. (Which is pretty much always the case with questions blaming password_hash/verify.)

Comment: Magnus - thanks for your tip. Script works, create new user and all is ok. Maybe something with hashing were incorrect.
mario - I know, its my first learing project